"Cannot read properties of null" Following official DiscordJS (v14) guide
I am attempting to create a slash command for banning a user. I first tried simply porting my prefix command, however this didn't work. So I decided to check out the DiscordJS guide. On the guide website I found this : https://discordjs.guide/slash-commands/parsing-options.html#command-options
Now, I basically copied and pasted it to test out whether this would work or not, but it didn't. This is what my ban command's file looks like (src/Commands/Slash/Moderation/Ban.js) :
const { SlashCommandBuilder, PermissionFlagsBits } = require('discord.js');
const Logger = require('@utils/Logger');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('ban')
        .setDescription('Select a member and ban them.')
        .addUserOption(option =>
            option
                .setName('target')
                .setDescription('The member to ban')
                .setRequired(true))
        .addStringOption(option =>
            option
                .setName('reason')
                .setDescription('The reason for banning'))
        .setDefaultMemberPermissions(PermissionFlagsBits.BanMembers)
        .setDMPermission(false),

    async execute(interaction) {
        try {
            const target = interaction.options.getUser('target');
            const reason = interaction.options.getString('reason') ?? 'No reason provided';

            await interaction.reply(`Banning ${target.username} for reason: ${reason}`);
        } catch (error) {
            Logger.error(error);
            await interaction.reply({
                content: 'An error occurred while attempting to execute this command! Please report this to the developers.',
                ephemeral: true,
            });
        }
    },
};

This should work in theory, but for some reason it returns an error :
[11:47:07] [ERROR] TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'username')
I have tried to fix it, and I have also made sure this isn't an issue because of incorrect intents. Please help!

The error is telling you that target is null which means that interaction.options.getUser('target') returned null. You should consult the documentation for that method to see what it says about possible return values

Method docs - https://discord.js.org/docs/packages/discord.js/14.15.3/CommandInteractionOptionResolver:Class#getUser

I was able to fix the issue, and turns out it wasn't a problem with the code, as changing the token fixed it. (The other application has the same guild permissions and the same intents).

You should add an answer below

Done, I'll remember to do this from now on, thanks!

I was able to fix the issue, and turns out it wasn't a problem with the code, as changing the token fixed it. The other application has the same guild permissions and the same intents, and in the end I don't really know what was causing it in the first place.
Hope this helps anyone else who might be facing this issue!
